# Ошибка памяти C++

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

```
    // Gaus.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class matrix
{
private:
    int n;
    double **A;
    double *b;
    inline void ifend();
    void filling();
public:
    matrix() :n(0), A(NULL), b(NULL) {}
    matrix(int x) :n(x)
    {
        b = new double[n];
        A = new double *[n];
        for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
        {
            *A = new double[n];
        }
    }
    void constructor();
    void gauss();
    void show();
};
inline void matrix::ifend() //Проверка на заполнение размера матрицы
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << "The size of matrix not found";
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
}
void matrix::constructor() //Создание системы уравнений
{
    matrix::ifend();
    matrix::filling();
}
void matrix::filling() //Заполнение расширенного массива
{
    matrix::ifend();
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        system("pause");
        for (int j(0); j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "a" << i + 1 << j + 1 << " = ";
            system("pause");
            cin >> A[i][j];
            system("pause");
        }
        cout << "b" << i << " = ";
        cin >> b[i];
    }
}
void matrix::show()
{
    matrix::ifend();
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j] << " * x" << j + 1;
            if (j == n - 1)
                cout << " = " << b[i];
            else
                cout << " + ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    matrix obj1(3);
    obj1.constructor();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Выходит ошибка при заполнении A[2][1] т.е. во второй строчке массива. Я как-то неправильно выделяю память под двумерный массив? Первая строчка заполняется норм.

Comment: У вас утечка памяти (нет деструктора и память из-под матрицы не освобождается) и есть метод, который называется "конструктор", хотя является инициализатором.

Answer (score 5):

Вот это

```
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        *A = new double[n];
    }
```

замените на

```
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[n];
    }
```

А то вы всю память только для первого ряда присваиваете...

Answer (score 3):

В этом цикле в конструкторе

```
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        *A = new double[n];
    }
```

имеет место утечка памяти, так как при каждой итерации цикла адрес выделяемой памяти перезаписывается в переменной `*A`, или, что тоже самое, в `A[0]`.

Правильно будет записать цикл как

```
    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[n];
    }
```

Обратите внимание, что у вас дублируется вызов функции `ifend`

```
void matrix::constructor() //Создание системы уравнений
{
    matrix::ifend();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    matrix::filling();
}
void matrix::filling() //Заполнение расширенного массива
{
    matrix::ifend();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Можно убрать этот вызов из функции `filling`